# How to download multiple images from a URL

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the below code working.  I think this is close, but I keep getting an error that reads 'unexpected EOF while parsing' on the last line.

```
import requests
import subprocess
import os
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

os.chdir("C:/Users/Excel/Downloads/")

request = requests.get("http://ottofrello.dk/malerierstor.htm")
content = request.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
element = soup.find_all("img")
for img in element:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://ottofrello.dk/" + img.get('src') + "," + img.get('src') + ")"
```

I am using Python 3.6.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis. For future reference: EOF is end of file, the python interpreter is saying it was expecting something in  your code but hit an EOF. Typically if you see a debug statement like that, you should look to see if you left out a quote character or a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to rewrite the last line as:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://ottofrello.dk/" + img.get('src'), img.get('src'))
```

still you'll get occasional errors when the image path is not just a file name, but an actual path, but you'll be going in the right direction, and can solve this later.

Comment: Thanks lenik.  That was it.  I am still trying to get used to Python.  This is quite different from many other languages that I've worked with in the past.  How did you figure that out?  I am using Spyder.  I selected all text, hit Ctrl+F11, and nothing happened.  On the Debug Menu, Ctrl+F11 is supposed to let a user step into the code, but it actually does nothing.

Comment: @ryguy72 you're welcome! =) I don't use complicated IDE, I just type my python statements on the punch cards. Makes me think twice before making mistakes =)